# FindElement() NOT working when application is getting triggered by task scheduler

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have created a console application using VS 2017 Professional IDE using Selenium framework in C#. This is an automated application, opening an IE browser performing some operations, and closing the browser once all the operations are performed. We completed all positive and negative testing locally (running in debugging and without debugging mode on VS) and it is working as per the expectation.

I need to configure the application in the task scheduler. In the task scheduler, inside ‘General’ Tab when I select ‘Run only when user is logged on’, I can see the console window is launching, which is subsequently launching the IE browser and performing the operations. In short it is working.

[image: Image 1]

The problem is when I select the option ‘Run whether user is logged in or not’ inside ‘General’ tab, the application works in the background (I can’t see the console window and browser launching, but logs are getting generated.). The application is giving a timeout exception for below statements:

> **driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUploadButtonControl")).SendKeys(path);     driver.FindElement(By.Id("ButtonName")).Click();**

[image: Image 2]

Nuget package I am using:

1. Selenium.WebDriver v4.0.0
2. Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver v3.150.

Browser - IE version 11

Exception details:

1. The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63638/session/335b5515-69f8-4340-943d-ca06b1c991da/element/6c289ae0-e500-42dc-82bc-1b77590319eb/value timed out after 120 seconds.-> getting exception for **driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUploadButtonControl")).SendKeys(path);**
2. The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:62712/session/4a553643-2690-4984-b2ad-2d74c39e370c/window timed out after 120 seconds. -> getting exception for **driver.FindElement(By.Id("ButtonName")).Click();**

It would be extremely helpful if anybody could get us out of this tricky situation.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the response status like 200 OK.  It is strange that the timeout is in both cases 120 seconds.  I suspect the server is closing the connection due to connection being idle for 2 minutes.  Check if the mode is http 1.0 (stream mode) or 1.1 (chunk mode).  Chunk mode requires after getting 100 continue a next chunk message.  If you do not send the next chunk the server will give a timeout error.

Comment: I kept waiting time of the driver for 2 mins so the connection is not an issue.

Comment: My guess is that the driver is not able to find the elements when the application runs in the background. This is only guesswork because I am getting an exception only when I trigger it via task schedular by selecting ‘Run whether user is logged in or not’ inside ‘General’ tab of Task schedular.So is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Don't guess.  Use a sniffer!!!

Comment: Try to run your task with highest privileges. Try to check the Run with highest privileges check box. Check whether it makes any difference or not.

Comment: I did. But that too didn't help. Instead IE, I used google chrome and it is working now. That may be because IE doesn't support headless functionality while chrome does. So when I triggered the application via task scheduler, the application runs in headless mode.

Comment: I still think that the issue is related to the task scheduler option 'run whether user is logged in or not' because same application is working with the option 'Run only when user is logged on'. Is your code have any references for external files? If yes, can you please show the relevant code about it? It may help to narrow down the issue.